# How I can save the model python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

**I am trying to save the model for use it in the web application but I get this error **

```
X = []
sentences = list(review_df['text'])
for sen in sentences:
X.append(clean_text(sen))
y = review_df['Label']

y = np.array(list(map(lambda x: 1 if x=="fake" else 0, y)))
```

#Text Classification with Recurrent Neural Network (LSTM)

```
from keras.layers.recurrent import LSTM
model = Sequential()
embedding_layer = Embedding(vocab_size, 100, weights=[embedding_matrix], input_length=maxlen , 
trainable=False)
model.add(embedding_layer)
model.add(LSTM(128))

model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['acc'])
print(model.summary())
```

#train the model

```
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=128, epochs=6, verbose=1, validation_split=0.2)
score = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, verbose=1)
```

#print model results

```
print("Test Score:", score[0])
print("Test Accuracy:", score[1])
```

#Making Predictions on Single Instance

```
instance = X[57]
print(instance)
instance = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(instance)

flat_list = []
for sublist in instance:
for item in sublist:
flat_list.append(item)

flat_list = [flat_list]

instance = pad_sequences(flat_list, padding='post', maxlen=maxlen)
model.predict(instance)
```

#save the model

```
import pickle
with open('model.pkl', 'wb') as f:
pickle.dump(model, f)
```

**when I try to save the model I get this error : TypeError: can't pickle _thread.RLock objects**
**Is there any idea for solving this error**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing this:

```
model_json = model.to_json()
with open("my_model.json", "w") as json_file:
    json_file.write(model_json)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save a keras model directly by:
`model.save('path/xyz.h5')`
It is Recommended to save model in H5 format and use `model.save()`
You can also load the format with `model.load()`